# Kamailio Multi Registrar Solution

Tags: mysql, asterisk, sip, kamailio

**About me**
I am very new to the use of Kamailio solution have basic background in practical application of SIP

**Overview**

I am tasked with building a Kamailio solution as a Active / Active Registrar

[Kamailio Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNh5u.jpg)

**Questions**

- Which modules would you user and why?
- Is there any good resources on the web to use?
- If User 1 rings User 2 how do we remove the requirement of specifying the IP of the kamaiio server that User2 is registered to?
- Is there any config examples that i could use to learn from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'll flag this question as *primarily opinion-based*, as answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 2):

With Multi Registrar Solution it means Configuring `Kamailio` to support `multiple Domains`

- In order to support `multi-Domain` you must look into 2 very important kamailio Modules  `Registrar Module` and  `Domain`
- `Registrar module` Details can be found here : http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.0.x/modules/registrar.html
- `Domain Module` Details can be found here :
  http://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.0.x/modules/domain.html
- also you' have to do some changes to  `kamailio.cfg` which by default restricts the calls to other domain by `myself`, where `myself` corrsponds to the local IP/ Domain of the Kamailio instance .
- Within `kamailio.cfg` you'll have to change all  `myself` to `is_uri_host_local()`.

Answer (score 1):

Kamailio project is hi-perfomance sip proxy.

All modules designed for rewrite of sip packets.

Config file is program similar to C.

So pre-request is advanced knowledge in programming and SIP protocol. Sorry, no other way.

Sure kamailio project have examples in examples directory and HUGE documentation at kamailio.org(take near month to fully read it).